# Windows Phone 8 IsTrial Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-8, marketplace

I have a Windows Phone 8 App and some extra features, which can only be used with the full version.

So the user clicks on a button

```
if ((Application.Current as App).IsTrial)
{
    Buy()
}
else
{
    //full feature
}


private void Buy()
    {
        MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
        marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "82a23635-5bd9-df11-a844-00237de2db9e";
        marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
    }
```

1. Is this all I have to do?
2. When the person buys the app, will the IsTrial automatically be set to false?
3. How do I change the ContentIdentifier if I don't even know the
   Identifier for my app  now?
4. Can I change the ContentIdentifier before I put my app in the store?

App.xaml

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The LicenseInformation class enables an application to determine 
    /// if it is running under a trial license.
    /// </summary>
    private static LicenseInformation _licenseInfo = new LicenseInformation();


    /// <summary>
    /// This property is used to cache the license information while the application is running. 
    /// The application uses the property whenever the current license information needs to be checked.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool _isTrial = true;
    public bool IsTrial
    {
        get
        {
            return _isTrial;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Check the current license information for this application
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckLicense()
    {

        _isTrial = _licenseInfo.IsTrial();

    }
```

Comment: Have you tested your code?

Comment: Everything works as it's supposed to work. But I mean if I put my app in the app store, will the IsTrial being set to active automatically when the user buys the app? I can't set '(Application.Current as App).IsTrial' to true, since it's ReadOnly.

Comment: There are ways to test this code by mocking a purchase.  I suggest you do that.

Comment: You've asked 4 questions in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your 2nd question.

Yes, Microsoft sets the **LicenseInformation.IsTrial** value based on user actions.  If the user buys the app, then the **IsTrial** is set to false.

You should test all your purchase scenarios before submitting to the store.  You test with the [CurrentAppSimulator  class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx).  It works in conjunction with a local XML file.  You populate the XML file with the simulated licenseinfomation for each scenario.

Regard question #3, you don't need specify a GUID, If you leave ContentIdentifier null the OS will look up your app GUID for you.

Comment: Did you mean to say if the user buys the app then IsTrail is set to false?

Comment: @Jeffv, yes, that's what I meant.  :>